# Running Quercus PHP inside Java

Tags: java, quercus

I am trying to run some PHP snippets from my Java application.

I have seen this question:
[PHP Call from Java Using Quercus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298123/php-call-from-java-using-quercus)

which suggests simply:

```
import com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine;

QuercusEngine engine = new QuercusEngine();
engine.setOutputStream(System.out);
engine.executeFile("src/test.php");
```

and I have seen http://wiki.caucho.com/Quercus%3a_Command_Line_Interface_%28CLI%29 which indicates:

```
QuercusEngine engine = new QuercusEngine();
engine.setIni("foo", "bar");
engine.execute("<?php var_dump(ini_get('foo')); ?>");
```

But on doing that, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.caucho.quercus.QuercusErrorException: eval::1: Fatal Error: 'var_dump' is an unknown function.
        at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.error(Env.java:6559)
        at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.error(Env.java:6445)
        at com.caucho.quercus.env.Env.error(Env.java:6109)
        at com.caucho.quercus.expr.CallExpr.evalImpl(CallExpr.java:198)
        at com.caucho.quercus.expr.CallExpr.eval(CallExpr.java:151)
        at com.caucho.quercus.expr.Expr.evalTop(Expr.java:523)
        at com.caucho.quercus.statement.ExprStatement.execute(ExprStatement.java:67)
        at com.caucho.quercus.program.QuercusProgram.execute(QuercusProgram.java:413)
        at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine.execute(QuercusEngine.java:139)
        at com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine.execute(QuercusEngine.java:100)
```

I get the same thing for any function -- strlen, strcmp, phpinfo, etc.

As described on http://quercus.caucho.com/ ...

> The Quercus .war file can be run on Java application servers such as
>   Glassfish, i.e. it can be run outside of Resin. This .war file
>   includes the Quercus interpreter and the PHP libraries.

I have downloaded the war file from that page (http://caucho.com/download/quercus-4.0.25.war)

and am running

```
$ javac -cp 'WEB-INF/lib/resin.jar;.' TestQuercus.java
$ java -cp 'WEB-INF/lib/resin.jar;.' TestQuercus
```

the complete file is

```
import com.caucho.quercus.QuercusEngine;

public class TestQuercus {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    QuercusEngine engine = new QuercusEngine();
    engine.setIni("foo", "bar");
    engine.execute("<?php var_dump(ini_get('foo')); ?>");
    }

}
```

I *am* able to do

```
java -cp 'WEB-INF/lib/resin.jar' com.caucho.quercus.CliQuercus foo.php
```

where foo.php includes `<?php phpinfo; ?>`

So how can I get from there to a working QuercusEngine?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as below.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import com.caucho.quercus.script.QuercusScriptEngineFactory;

QuercusScriptEngineFactory factory = new QuercusScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine();

String code = "<?php $foo = strlen('abc'); print $foo; return 'yikes'; ?>";
Object o = engine.eval(code);
System.out.println(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug.  I just fixed it for 4.0.33, which should be out pretty soon.  If you like, you can build Quercus yourself from our public svn repository:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.caucho.com/home/svn/svnroot/resin/trunk resin
cd resin
ant
```

Jars will be resin/lib/resin-kernel.jar and resin/lib/quercus.jar.

For bug reference, see http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5270.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your response.  I am marking my own answer as the answer for now, though, because it works for the distributed source (vs trunk).